# why octal number system jumping from 7 to 10 instead 8?

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

I know the question is really confusing but I have a questin about Octal number system. I am reading a book and on the counting in octal as shown

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,....,16,17,20 ?

why does the number is not followed by 8,18,19 and so on?

thanks!

Comment: Why in the decimal number system does it jump straight from $9$ to $10$?  Why is $9$ not followed immediately by $\clubsuit$ or $\flat$?

Comment: oh thank you for the better question! I will edit it ! :)

Comment: @Bye_World best comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not confusing at all!  The jump from 7 to 10 is precisely the point!  The octal system represents numbers in base 8, which means that each digit represents a power of 8.  Therefore, the 1's place only needs the digits 0-7, and the number 10 in octal (NOT the decimal number 10), is $1\times8^1 + 0\times8^0 = 8$ in decimal.

Comment: but is there any reason why it goes to 10 or it is just the theory that I need memorize? after 7 so it jumps to 10 and when I count 10-17 is octal and then I go to 20 and so on right?

Comment: It jumps from 7-10 in the same way that decimal jumps from 9-10. The latter just feels more natural because we are used to decimal. Ultimately, what is happening is that we have reached the capacity of the units place and moved onto the tens place, as the answer explains.

Comment: yes, pretend that you grew up, and you only knew the digits 0-7 (suppose humans only had 4 fingers in each hand).  Then the transition from 7 to 10 wouldn't seem that weird...and instead of counting by [decimal] 10s, you would count by [decimal] 8s, but you would write it 10, 20, 30, etc. So there are lots of ways to write any quantity, base 10 is just the most familiar.  Base 2 is very important in computers, and you only have 2 digits!